# how to write xml instance data for a given yang file

Tags: xml, netconf, yang

I am learning netconf and yang. One thing which confuses me is, how to write an XML instance data for a given yang schema. Is there a tool which can create a sample instance data? Where I can just put my own values without worrying about nodes, and it's nesting.

eg for below given yang model

```
module tubecats {
    namespace "http://plajjan.github.io/ns/yang/tubecats";
    prefix tc;

    revision 2017-03-15 {
        description "First and only version";
    }

    container internet {
        list cat {
            key name;
            leaf name {
                type string;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How below sample instance data is generated?

```
<ns0:data xmlns:ns0="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <tc:internet xmlns:tc="http://plajjan.github.io/ns/yang/tubecats">
        <tc:cat>
            <tc:name>jingles</tc:name>
        </tc:cat>
        <tc:cat>
            <tc:name>fluffy</tc:name>
        </tc:cat>
    </tc:internet>
</ns0:data>
```

I understand there is a tool called yanglint which can validate model again instance data but that is not what I want.

Comment: Questions like this (asking for tool recommendations) are [not a good fit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site. That being said, [pyang](https://github.com/mbj4668/pyang) has a plugin that generates skeleton instance documents if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [`netconf-cli`](https://github.com/CESNET/netconf-cli) which has a `yang-cli` command line utility. With this, you can do something like the following:

```
$ yang-cli --configonly path/to/your/tubecats.yang
/> create tc:internet/cat[name="Micinka"]
```

There's tab completion which should get you going, and you can print the datatsore content as JSON:

```json
/> dump json
{
  "tc:internet": {
    "cat": [
      {
        "name": "Micinka"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

...or XML:

```xml
/> dump xml
<tc xmlns="http://plajjan.github.io/ns/yang/tubecats">
  <cat>
    <name>Micinka</name>
  </cat>
</tc>
```